# Locks and keys: Number of trials

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I wanna clarify just one point:-
I think the number of trials to open the first lock is $n-1$ and not $n$. For example if I have $5$ locks and $5$ keys then to open the first lock I'll try $4$ keys only and if none of that works then obviously the remaining fifth key is the matching key. So in this way I'm getting no. of trials  $= (n-1) + (n-2) + ...... + (1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Am I right?

Comment: No, because knowing that the final key will open the lock isn't the same as actually opening the lock.  The question asks you how many trials it will take to actually get the locks open, not how many trials it will take to figure out which key matches which lock.

Comment: Ah yes, now I got it.

Comment: The question is about number of trial needed to open, not number of trials needed to deduce the lock pattern. Your reasoning is right when it comes to deducing the key matches. You need to use another $n$ attempts, then, to actually open each lock.